# Laplace-Beltrami operator for Kahler 2-form

Tags: differential-geometry

Laplace-Beltrami operator for Kahler 2-form: $$\triangle\Omega(X,Y)=d\delta\Omega(X,Y)+\delta d\Omega(X,Y)$$
We know that $$\delta d\Omega(X,Y)=-\sum_{k}(\nabla_{e_{k}}d\Omega(e_{k},X,Y))$$ where $\{e_{1},...,e_{k}\}$ are orthonotmal basis. 
How can I compute $$\delta d\Omega(X,Y)=???$$ using the same orthonormal basis.

Comment: Kahler form is harmonic.

Comment: Have a look here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242857/kahler-form-is-harmonic